# Why can the multiple assignments be separated by space in Shell

Tags: shell

In shell, why can these two assignments be separated by space?

```
foo="foo" bar="bar"
```

As we know, commands separated by a ‘;’ are executed sequentially. What about the space?

Answer (score 2):

It is not separated independent commands; actually it is not commands at all.

It's just syntax of a command line: you can set some variables before running a command. The variables are set only for this command.

```
var1=val1 var2=val2... cmd
```

> A simple command is **a sequence of optional variable assignments**
>   followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by
>   a control operator. The first word specifies the command to be
>   executed, and is passed as argument zero. The remaining words are
>   passed as arguments to the invoked command.

Answer (score 2):

The **SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION** section of `man bash` explains the syntax:

> ```
> SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION
>        When  a  simple  command  is executed, the shell performs the following
>        expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
>        1.     The words that the parser has  marked  as  variable  assignments
>               (those  preceding  the  command name) and redirections are saved
>               for later processing.
>
>        2.     The words that are not variable assignments or redirections  are
>               expanded.   If  any words remain after expansion, the first word
>               is taken to be the name of the command and the  remaining  words
>               are the arguments.
>
>        3.     Redirections are performed as described above under REDIRECTION.
>
>        4.     The text after the = in each variable assignment undergoes tilde
>               expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>               expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the  vari-
>               able.
>
>        If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current
>        shell environment.  Otherwise, the variables are added to the  environ-
>        ment  of the executed command and do not affect the current shell envi-
>        ronment.  If any of the assignments attempts to assign  a  value  to  a
>        readonly  variable,  an error occurs, and the command exits with a non-
>        zero status.
>
>        If no command name results, redirections  are  performed,  but  do  not
>        affect  the  current shell environment.  A redirection error causes the
>        command to exit with a non-zero status.
>
>        If there is a command name left after expansion, execution proceeds  as
>        described  below.   Otherwise, the command exits.  If one of the expan-
>        sions contained a command substitution, the exit status of the  command
>        is  the  exit  status  of  the last command substitution performed.  If
>        there were no command substitutions, the command exits with a status of
>        zero.
> ```

Point 1 clearly allows multiple variable assignments before a command name.

The paragraphs after the points clearly allow assignments without any command name.

Comment: I also find the following helpful `EXPANSION Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words` Meaning, word splitting is applied to any number of space-separate assignments prior to variable expansion taking place.